# How to call the SimpleCaddy plugin in a module?

Tags: events, plugins, joomla, module, system

I'm using the SimpleFileLoader module and would like have the SimpleCaddy plugin to be placed next each uploaded image. I know where to place the plugin call in the HTML/PHP code but don't know how to call the SimpleCaddy plugin to have the Add Cart button show.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

[ModulesAnywhere](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere) might help you out.

Comment: ModulesAnywhere is a content plugin that takes modules. SimplyCaddy is a content plugin. I need SimplyCaddy to run as a system plugin in the HTML string in the SimpleFileLoader module.